# Visual/animation for an order success/confirmation screen

Tags: web-app, e-commerce, mobile-application, checkout

Designing the final screen of a checkout funnel on an ecommerce app. What would  be a suitable visual or animation for this? I've looked at a few apps and websites, but most of them have just a thank you message.

Below this visual/animation there will also be a order summary details.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that e-commerce implies a credit card transaction, the final animation should depict money leaving a credit card and entering a zone which is marked by the logo of the merchant's website.  A smiling mascot or the ubiquitous "Thank you" message should greet the money's arrival, conveying the merchant's gratitude for the successful sale.  A promise of prompt delivery can then complete the animated sequence.